# Can "Extend Selection" aka ctrl+. be used in the workbench?

Tags: keyboard, workbench

Extend Selection (Ctrl+.) is likely the most useful mathematica keyboard shortcut for me.

Is it available in the Wolfram Workbench?

Naively pressing Ctrl+. doesn't do anything and searching the documentation for "Extend Selection" turns up nothing.

Comment: It is available in the IntelliJ plugin (Option-Up on macOS). I no longer use the Workbench for editing so I cannot answer that.

Comment: @Szabolcs Good to know that the feature is available in the InteliJ plugin. I only tested the workbench briefly, but it looks like the InteliJ plugin is more suitable to my editing needs. If it works for me, I'll probably ditch the workbench. Thx, for the input.

Comment: For just editing, I highly recommend the IntelliJ plugin. The things that are only available in the Workbench, not not the IntelliJ plugin: documentation generation, profiling, debugging. Of these, I only use the Workbench for documentation generation.